# Incomprehensible 502 error Java Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to work with particular website and I use Jsoup:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

But when I get document - `org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=502, URL=url`. And this is strange because I can connect to the website in browser. What do you think about this???

Comment: It's a [Bad Gateway](https://httpstatuses.com/502) response. Do you perhaps have a proxy configured you're not aware of?

Comment: 502 is bad gateway. Is your browser passing through a proxy while your app tries to connect directly?

Comment: @Henrik As far as I know, no.

Comment: Try using an HttpURLConnection and changing the headers (in particular the User-Agent header), and see if this can download the html

Comment: @Xlsx it didn't help me. Lets look at these URLs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions and https://stackoverflow.com. These URLs are examples. First URL i can't get, but i can get the second.

Comment: @Xlsx I think I need first of all connect to the second url, then send a request and go to the first url, because I can't connect at once to the first.

Comment: When I run `Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://stackoverflow.com/questions").get();` it works fine. Maybe the 502 error was only a temporary internal server error?

Comment: @Xlsx I used them just for example, in fact it works for me, too. Try this link http://zk.fm/mp3/search?keywords=Example

Comment: I get a 502 when visiting that site in the browser, maybe that site is down right now?

Comment: @Xlsx omg, it works for me, in browser

Comment: I went to the homepage of the website, and then went to that link and it worked. The website is definitely looking at the cookies sent with the request.

Comment: @Xlsx so what I should do?

Comment: Add the `Cookie: ZvcurrentVolume=100; zvAuth=1; zvLang=0; ZvcurrentVolume=100; notice=11` header to the jsoup request

Comment: This works for me: `Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://zk.fm/mp3/search?keywords=Example").header("Cookie", "ZvcurrentVolume=100; zvAuth=1; zvLang=0; ZvcurrentVolume=100; notice=11").get();`

Comment: @Xlsx it works for me too. Thank you very much for help!